# Can you preload a video using the YoutTubePlayer for Android SDK

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm creating an app which allows playing multiple YouTube videos in a playlist.  Id like to reduce the start time for each video and also to allow playback which there is drop in connection.

Is it possible to preload videos via the API?